# Dual-Boot Confusion

Tags: dual-boot

Ok, so I recently used a lot of Windows 7 and downloaded a bunch of stuff on there that I don't want to use, so I am using a separate hard drive now with Ubuntu. But on the Linux OS, it's saying that I haven't got a lot of space left, I haven't downloaded anything except for maybe 5 or 6 small files and it's saying that I have 500 megabytes left. I'm pretty sure I'm using a whole new hard drive that has 500 gigs of memory.

I probably made a mistake during the setup and put only 700 or so megabytes in Ubuntu, if I did please tell me how I can put more memory in!

Picture of Gparted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPmR1.jpg

(I meant Megabytes, sorry!)

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but just to make it easy for everyone who looks at this thread, I highly doubt you mean millabyte. A millabyte would be 1/1000 of a byte, which doesn't exist. If the message said MB or MiB then you mean Megabytes or Mebibytes respectively.

Comment: You can use *Disk Space Analyzer* to see where all that space goes!

Comment: open a terminal and post output of "sudo df -h" and of "more /etc/fstab". This will tell you how much space you actually have and where.

Comment: Upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and then provide the link here.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using WUBI.EXE?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: You only show NTFS partitions, so you have to have installed with wubi. Wubi uses the Windows boot loader and is just a file inside the Windows NTFS partition. Wubi has a Max of 30GB. Note that since wubi does not work with the new UEFI systems 12.04 is the last supported version. May be better to do a full install to a separate partition.

Comment: So I installed it on Windows?

Comment: You show Gparted screenshot of the wrong drive (1 TB HDD)? Use the button in the right upper corner in the Gparted-window to select second drive and add one more screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live media, then use the Gparted on it to expand the partition with low space

Answer (score 0):

first, Ubuntu needs 5 GB to install in the first place, but
**to check if your system is *really* only above the required space**, go to the file browser, ("Files") right click "computer" in the left coloum(second to bottom icon, and did I spell that right?) and click properties. under the key for the pie chart. It'll tell you what you have in total. If you *did* screw this up, you're going to have to go through the installation process again, which sucks, but I have no idea what else you can do.